# Does the allocated memory in java remain there for following code

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

```
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    List<Integer> ls =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ls.add(1);
}
```

After each iterations, does the allocated memory still remains there. I mean I want to free them. If I want it not be there, what should I do?

I met a outOfmemory problem, I do not know whether it is caused by this kind of thing or not

Comment: How could it remain there if you have no way to access `ls`?

Comment: @SSpoke This is partially correct. The memory space IS allocated by the JVM. I'm not factoring in any potential optimizations which might factor this whole thing out. But the memory is not reclaimed immediately. The GC will run whenever it wants.

Comment: I face a problem out of memory wether it caused by those kind of things for a huge amount of data?

Comment: Use a Java Profiling tool to figure out where it happened, I usually get downvoted when I advise people to use `System.gc();` but it may help.

Comment: This code is not causing your out of memory problem. It is however completely pointless.

Comment: I realize I need to enlargen the maximum memory use for eclipse, but when I input -Xmx2048m it does not work, why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I find that I need to enlargen the vm setting for eclipse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is a local variable inside the `for` loop. This means that once an iteration is done, it **can** be garbage collected, and is indeed marked as such.
Whether the JVM decides to collect it or not is an entirely different matter, and is up to the JVM's implementation. It can be effected by parameters you pass to java (e.g., `-Xms`, `-Xmx` or the notorious `-XX:` parameters), but can't strictly be controlled.